# How do I use JavaScript so that only the certain nav bar gets clicked on is highlighted at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So in my website, I have a navigation bar that navigates through my page. I wrote css code for it so on hover, it changes to gold and a white bar appears underneath it. I want to know if theres a script I could use so that when you click on one of those navigation links, it stays the way it is on hover and resets when another nav link is clicked on. Heres my CSS code so you get the idea:

```css
.Home-link::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 1s;
}
.Home-link:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
    color: gold;
}

.Home-link:hover{
    color: gold;
}
```

```html
 <section class="nav">
    <div class="nav-links">
       <a href="#TitlePage" class="Home-link">Home</a>
       <a href="#about" class="about-link">About</a>
       <a href="#Experience" class="Experience-link">Experience</a>
    </div>                             
</section>
```

Comment: Remove 'active' class from all menu items and add 'active' class to clicked item. Don't forget to add `.active` styles into your CSS.

Comment: @pavel im trying to write a script in JavaScript so that this hover code stays active once Home link is clicked or on the Home page if that makes sense, but i have no idea

Comment: Please add relevant HTML code.

Comment: @pavel added the code

Answer (score 0):

I can interpret your question in two ways, so I'll try to answer both.

### Just focusing elements without changing the page

> when you click on one of those navigation links, it stays the way it is on hover and resets when another nav link is clicked on

This tells me you're looking for `:focus` (or its younger cousin, `:focus-within`; this depends on your document structure).

Elements get focused when the user tabs to them or when they get clicked on. Tabbing out or clicking elsewhere removes the focus.

You can combine selectors so that both `:hover` and `:focus` do the same thing, like this:

```css
.Home-link:hover,
.Home-link:focus {
    color: gold;
}
```

### Navigating from page to page

However, if you're looking for a more permanent solution – marking your navbar items as "this is the page you're on", you need to apply a class like `active` (or whatever other name you like) to the proper item.

A solution for something like this heavily depends on your project/framework. In vanilla JavaScript, you could check the current location (`window.location.href`) and, depending on its content, add the `active` class to specific navbar item.

```js
if (window.location.href.contains('/home')) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('Home-link')[0]?.classList.add('active');
}
```

Then, in CSS:

```css
.Home-link:hover,
.Home-link.active {
    color: gold;
}
```

Comment: I tried everything in css and nothing worked, im trying to turn to JavaScript without messing the css code I already have. Do you have any idea of how I would write a javaScript line for this ?

Comment: No, focus won't work when I click somewhere else into document. Than I expect the tab should be still active.

Comment: The updated question clears it a bit. So you only scroll to a relevant anchor in the page and want its nav item highlighted? It's way more complex than the initial question suggests, because the highlight should be updated once user scrolls to another section of your page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in following way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var links = $('.customcss').click(function () {
                links.removeClass('CurrActive');
                links.removeClass('a');
                $(this).addClass('CurrActive');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .Home-link::after {
            content: '';
            width: 0%;
            height: 3px;
            background: white;
            display: block;
            transition: 1s;
        }

        .Home-link:hover::after {
            width: 100%;
            color: gold;
        }

        .Home-link:hover {
            color: gold;
        }

        .CurrActive {
            color: gold;
        }
        a:focus, a:hover {
            color: gold;
            outline: 0
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <section class="nav">
                <div class="nav-links">
                    <a href="#TitlePage" class="Home-link customcss">Home</a>
                    <a href="#about" class="about-link customcss">About</a>
                    <a href="#Experience" class="Experience-link customcss">Experience</a>
                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```